# Как решить проблему с работой Gmail в Mail.app на MacOs?

Tags: macos, gmail

Последнии 3 месяца наблюдая проблемы c **gmail** в стандартном приложение  **Mail.app** в MacOS HIGH SIERRA. Письма перестают приходить и приложение просит заново ввести пароль от учетной записи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нагуглил что нужно зайти в настройки gmail и отключить **imap**. И это помогло, но примерно на 2 недели. Сейчас подобные манипуляции с включением/отключением imap не дают результатов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема с двухфакторной авторизацией. Решил так:

**1.** Создал пароль для приложений в настройках gmail.

**2.** Удалил из настроек macos учетную запись gmail с вдухфакторной авторизацией.

**3.** Добавил аккаунт gmail с паролем полученным в первом пункте.